# Biblehub.com versus Bible.cc - are both links legit?

Tags: discussion

This is tangential to this site but I'm hoping I can get an answer here because Biblehub has no support. After using Biblehub.com for a while I get another link, bible.cc that when I click it it opens up Biblehub.com. Is this how it is supposed to work or is that a malicious link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From their [About Us](https://biblehub.com/about.htm) page:

> ### Our History
>
> The Online Parallel Bible Project began in 2004 as Bible.cc, which provided a parallel, verse by verse view of 8 translations. Soon, many new tools were developed to support the parallel site. These began as separate sites, but our feedback led us to develop a single integrated platform. Thus, in 2007 several sites were integrated to form Biblos.com and later BibleHub.com.

In other words this is their own old domain. It looks like all links to it or directly forwarded (via `HTTP 301, permanently moved` headers) to their current canonical domain.

Also based on this I would expect to find other legacy domains now associated with and pointing to biblehub.com.

Comment: Thanks, that's a load off my mind!

Comment: One of the most exciting of these other domains is [biblemenus.com](http://biblemenus.com/), which lists an enormous amount of files used by them, including a 151MB interlinear excel sheet :-) (I don't know whether it is intentional that this site is public, or what the license of that data is.)