# Hermeneutic tools

Tags: discussion, scope, meta

Recently two questions about other tools were asked on Hermeneutics Meta (this site): one on [biblehub.com](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3527/2672) and one on [BDAG](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3520/2672). A question on the main site about [searching in the Vulgate](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/34834/2672) currently has two close votes to migrate it to Hermeneutics Meta.

As I understand it, [Meta is for discussing the main site](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta): it is **meta-Hermeneutics.SE**, not **meta-hermeneutics**. So these questions do not have a place on Hermeneutics Meta.

Do we want to give these questions a proper place on the main site? Then perhaps the [help center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) should be updated and include another bullet point, "tools for hermeneutic study" (I personally think that would be a good idea - we even already have [a tag](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools-of-biblical-studies) for it!).

But in any case, can we please keep Meta clean of these questions? They don't belong here.

Comment: What's that sound I hear? Is it the sound of Caleb cheering? 

Comment: But this has come up before: "[What should we do with questions about tools used in Biblical scholarship?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3209)" There is even a tag for these: [tag:tools-of-biblical-studies]. They do belong on Main (is my understanding) and "Meta" should be reserved for discussing issues arising on "Main", as Keelan points out. (Do we close "Duplicates" on Meta??)

Comment: @Dɑvïd thanks, I hadn't seen that earlier question. I will close it; having this question here hopefully brings it to the attention of the people concerned :-)